# Heteroskedacity in longitudinal data

Tags: r, model, mixed-models, mixed, linearmodels

[plot of residuals vs predicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QEuY.png) 
Hi all,

I have a linear mixed random intercept model in r.
I have applied this model to longitudinal/panel data of customers of a time period.
For each customer, i have a different intercept.
As i want to obtain their general effect over time to make conclusion i have chosen for a linear random intercept model.

For this model, as for each linear model, the error term has to be homoskedastic.

I want to test this assumption statiscally, however a bptest can't be applied because this assumes I.D.D.  So, next to my plot which i attached. Do you guys know any method to test this statiscally?

Thank you in advancw